# Read/Write large XMLs without using too much memory in PHP

Tags: php, xml, xmlreader, xmlwriter

I'm trying to query some very large XML files (up to several gig), check them for being well-formed, and write them to hard disk. Seems easy, but as they are so large I can not have a whole document in the memory. Therefore my question is:
**How can I read, check and write large XML files when less RAM is available than one document is in size?**

My Approach:
Read it node by node with XMLReader (if that succeeds the document must be well-formed) and use XMLWriter for writing. Problem: XMLWriter seems to store everything in RAM till the document is finalized. DOM Documents and SimpleXML seem to do the same. Is there anything else I could try?

Comment: Why don't you use an [XSD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML_Schema_(W3C)) to validate the XML?

Comment: @halloei It would be absolutely useful to be able to validate the document,  (instead of just checking for well-formed-ness) but unfortunately that is impossible due to its frequently changing structure.

Comment: This should not happen if you use `XMLWriter::openURI()`. It has an internal buffer so it does not write each method call, ut you can trigger that with `XMLWriter::flush()`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your approach seems suitable, to get around the RAM issue with XMLWriter you could try periodically flushing the memory into your output file.

```
<?php
$xmlWriter = new XMLWriter();
$xmlWriter->openMemory();
$xmlWriter->startDocument('1.0', 'UTF-8');
for ($i=0; $i<=10000000; ++$i) {
    $xmlWriter->startElement('message');
    $xmlWriter->writeElement('content', 'Example content');
    $xmlWriter->endElement();
    // Flush XML in memory to file every 1000 iterations
    if (0 == $i%1000) {
        file_put_contents('example.xml', $xmlWriter->flush(true), FILE_APPEND);
    }
}
// Final flush to make sure we haven't missed anything
file_put_contents('example.xml', $xmlWriter->flush(true), FILE_APPEND);`
```

Source: http://codeinthehole.com/tips/creating-large-xml-files-with-php/

Comment: Thanks a lot, I am going to try that, it really sounds like the way to go